# Show Bluetooth Device Chooser and Send File

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, tablet, kindle-fire

Sorry for not having any code, only an explanation of what I want to do. My robotics team is working on an app to rank robots, and we are trying to get the android tablets able to send files over to a rasberry pi via bluetooth.

We have seen the **Bluetooth Device Chooser** when trying to send a file over bluetooth, but have no idea on how to encorporate the popup into our app, or something similar.

Any assistance would be greatly appriceated. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind having the user specify they want to use bluetooth for the transfer a fairly easy way to accomplish this can be found [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/bluetooth-data-transfer-with-android.html)

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMulligan :)